# How do i manage request redirection from load balancer and apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

```
getRequest().getLocalAddr()
```

Application is switching in different ip when request is going to external ip domain name, then some time it taking load balancer ip and some time it taking apache ips either application tomcat ip

i am using this for getting ip for request,
when i am login then some time it taking load balancer IP and logout with different apache ip or tomcat server ip.

so why it taking different ips for same request.

Thanks

Comment: my server structure is = External Domain Name > Load Balancer > two apache server > every server also have 2 tomcat